# Align Text Item to the Center

Tags: html, css

I have this text:

[image]

How can I move that "Consultants" bit to the middle of the top two words, instead of on the left side like that.

Code (ignore the `margin-left`):

```
<h6 style="margin-left: 795px;">Connect with <br>Consultants</h6>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css `text-align`

```html
<h6 style="text-align:center">Connect with<br>Consultants</h6>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this

```
text-align: center;
```